# Global hotkeys for specific application with python3 on windows

Tags: python-3.x, hotkeys, pywinauto

I'm writing a script to control a specific application with hotkeys. I divided my task into three tasks:

1. monitor for global keys,
2. match pressed global hotkeys to keys to be sent,
3. send keys to specific application.

Let's say i want to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to Notepad.exe when i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> from anywhere. It's important that the application (notepad in this case) i want to control will not be in focus before i press hotkeys and after it.

I suppose task 3 is about to work with pywinauto and it's keyboard.SendKeys.  Task 2 is not difficult.  But i have no idea how to monitor (in cycle? depending on keyboard events?) for global hotkeys.

Comment: from pywinauto import win32_hooks

Comment: Typing from phone. Will post normal answer later.